# Load Silverlight App with Metro IE

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, windows-8, microsoft-metro, add-in

I have a Silverlight App running on web, I have installed the SL runtime with newest version and I can access it with `Desktop IE`. But I can't access it with `Metro IE`, it lets me to install the SL runtime. I have tried to reinstall the runtime but nothing changed. Has anyone know how to load SL App in Metro IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight, and basicly any other browser plugins, are disabled in Metro IE so you won't be able to do make it work there.

> Internet Explorer provides an add-on–free experience, so browser
>   plugins don't load and any dependent content isn't displayed. However,
>   Internet Explorer for the desktop does support browser plugins,
>   including ActiveX controls such as Adobe Flash and Microsoft
>   Silverlight.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846773.aspx

Comment: I also searched many docs and the result is same to yours.So I think the answer is like you said. Thanks!